# How do I stop PHPUnit emitting a stack trace for caught exceptions?

Tags: php, laravel-5, phpunit

I'm developing an application using Laravel, and I'm running into an issue with my unit tests.  For no apparent reason, PHPUnit is emitting the stack trace for *caught* exceptions.

```
public function testIndexMethodUnauthenticated(){
    $user = factory(App\User::class)->create();
    $response = $this->get('api/v1/users');
    $this->assertResponseStatus(400);
}
```

This test 'passes' quite successfully.  The call hits the API, fails to authenticate the user, and emits a JWT exception.  That exception is then caught in `App\Exceptions\Handler.php`, which renders an appropriate JSON representation of the error with a 400 status code.

All good, right?  Nope.  PHP unit them emits the stack trace for that error, despite the fact that the exception has already been caught and handled.  I'm assuming that it's (somehow?) creating an event handler that catches all exceptions, which is awesome, but how do I *suppress* the output thus created?

Another question suggested something like `$this->setExpectedException()`, but that just resulted in a failing test.

In and of itself, this one test emitting a stack trace isn't a huge issue.  But as I scale up the number of tests, this is going to (rapidly) become a serious issue.

Comment: I dont't think the exception trace is being emitted by PHPUnit. If the exception is really being caught in `App\Exceptions\Handler.php`, there is no way PHPUnit can detect it and dump the trace.

Comment: Not sure why Handler isn't catching this, but use PHPUnit annotations to 'hide' the issue if you wish to. // @expectedException App\Exception\SomeException

Comment: Another thought - have you overridden setUp() in the test class and forgot to call parent::setUp()? When the Laravel environment is not correctly setup, it can cause testing weirdness.

Comment: And finally, an open issue that seems to be the same https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/633

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer (late) last night.  PHPUnit isn't catching, logging, or anything else the exception.  The stacktrace was actually coming from Laravel's logging mechanism.  I had configured it to work properly on Heroku, and output to STDOUT instead of a log file.  I've changed that to use an environment variable instead, which defaults to using the log file but will use the proper STDOUT when on Heroku.

Edit:

Better yet, look a few lines up and see there is an entire array of exceptions that aren't reported.  Just add the 'handled' exception types to it, update as needed, and weeee!

Comment: can you please expand on this answer?  I am having the same issue

Comment: @JoshPetitt I'd love to, but honestly it's been a year since I did that and I just flat out don't remember what I was doing.